# how to get list of glassfish jndi references

Tags: jndi, glassfish-3

is there anyway to do a remote lookup on glassfish 3.1.2 (3.1.X)
and get back the list of possible jndi names. (With weblogic its easy, but with glassfish I can not seem to find a way and all my guesses at the jndi name of my ejb have failed)

Answer (score 2):

Use "asadmin list-jndi-entries"

asadmin has contextual help, as well as documentation [online](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gglpq.html), which might point you in the right direction.